# Nuxtjs & Nginx reverse proxy in a subdirectory

Tags: node.js, nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

Here is my Nginx configuration and it's not working.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /path {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

However, reverse proxy in `location /` is working. I think this is related to Nuxtjs but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nuxt, you shouldn't serve as a proxy pass.

You should use the following command to generate a build and serve the path with nginx. For more information you can check the [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands)

```
$ npm run build
$ npm run generate
```

After that command run with success you should see a new folder `dist` with your project.

You should serve `dist` folder in your nginx.

My nginx file example for serving nuxt project:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/site/dist;

    index index.html;

    server_name mydomain.com.br www.mydomain.com.br;
    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /path {
         alias /var/www/nuxtproj/dist; #<-- made this edit
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I'm going to serve it as a directory in `/path`

Comment: Are you sure this is a working solution? Also does it make sense to run `npm run build` after `npm run generate`? It's not working for me.

Comment: Just checking, maybe should run `build` first.

Comment: Actually you should run build before generate. Sorry.

Comment: Did you restarted nginx after change the nginx config file?